# How to use Chi-square test in dataset with negative values

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, scikit-learn

I could not fully explain the title. In order to use the Chi-square test in my dataset, I am finding the smallest value and add each cell with that value. (for example, the range of data here is [-8,11] so I added +8 to each cell and the range turned to [0,19]).

```
for i in range(len(dataValues.index)):
    for j in range(len(dataValues.columns)):
        dataValues.iat[i, j] += 8
```

After Preprocessing:

```
for i in range(len(dataValues.index)):
    for x in topFeatures:
        finalDataFrame.at[i, x] = dataValues.at[i, x] - 8
```

But this causes performance problems. Another solution I'm thinking of is to normalize it. I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
def normalization(df):
    from sklearn import preprocessing

    x = df.values  # returns a numpy array
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns=df.columns)

    return df
```

My program has accelerated lots, but this time my accuracy has decreased. The feature selection process I have done with the first method produces 0.85 accuracy results, this time I am producing 0.70 accuracy.

I want to get rid of this primitive method, but I also want accuracy to remain constant. How do I proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider asking your question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I did. For now Im waiting for realiable answers from both sides.